# php search form echoes all variables correctly on results page except id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple search form that works well and gives the results from the search successfully on my results1.php search results page.

HOWEVER, I cannot get this results page to echo the id correctly. It just echoes "1" as the value id for all result rows. But the names and any other data I want to display echoes correctly. Why is the id not working? Is it because query doesn't know what id to return because it is a join query? I tried $row['casino.id'] but that doesn't work either...

Here is the code:

```
//index.html page FORM
<form action="results1.php" method="GET">
<b>Store Type:</b><select name="type">
<option value="retail" selected>Retail
<option value="wholesale">Wholesale
</select>
<br>
<b>Currenncy Choice:</b><select name="currency">
<option value="">Any
<option value="bitcoin">Bitcoin
<option value="Euros">Euros
<option value="U.S. Dollars">US Dollars
</select>
<br>
</select>
<INPUT type="submit" border="0" value="Submit" alt="Submit">
</form>


//The results1.php page

$type = $_GET['type'];
$currency = $_GET['currency'];

$query = "(
SELECT * FROM stores
LEFT JOIN stores_banking SB ON stores.id=SB.stores_id
LEFT JOIN banking B ON  SB.banking_id = B.id
LEFT JOIN stores_gaming SG ON stores.id=CG.stores_id
LEFT JOIN gaming G ON  SG.gaming_id = G.id
WHERE 
('$type' IS NULL OR '$type' = '' OR G.type = '$type')
And
('$currency' IS NULL OR '$currency' = '' OR B.currency= '$currency')
GROUP BY stores.name
Order by stores.id
)";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>id</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";    //NOT WORKING...always returns "1"
echo "</tr>";
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` your `$result` var plz and show us the result ?

Comment: Sure. Here it is: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(30) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Because your tables all contain id so the fields will be named tablename.id ... var_dump or print_r and let us know your result

Comment: @ntirex I just shared var_dump results in the comment above yours...

Comment: can you var_dump a row in your `while ($row ==mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` loop also plz

Comment: and when I change it to stores.id I get "Undefined index"

Comment: Can you Print_r $row inside the foreach and show us what it will display?

Comment: here it is, broken into 2 comments to fit it all here: Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => TestStore1 [rank] => 4 [link] => https://test.com [quality] => 98.7 [safe] => Y [us] => Yes [language] => English [bonus] => welcome coupon  [live] => bi [crypto] => Y [mobile] => [speed] => 3 Confirmations (2-10 minutes) [software] => basic [products] => all [jurisdiction] => Cost Rica [license] => State Commission [owned] => Taylor Co. => store.png [features] => lots of products [cons] => not many locations [description] => [store_id] => 1 [banking_id] => 1 [currency] => Bitcoin

Comment: [product_id] => 1 [type] => retail ) Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => TestStore2 [rank] => 0 [link] => [quailty] => [safe] => [us] =>No [language] => [bonus] => [live] => [crypto] => [mobile] => [speed] => [software] => [products] => [jurisdiction] => [license] => [owned] => [logo] => [features] => [cons] => [description] => [store_id] => 2 [banking_id] => 4 [currency] => Japanese Yen [product_id] => 1 [type] => wholesale )

Comment: above are 2 results for the search I did. So the above is the print_r results for these results

Comment: so strange...it does show two arrays for 2 diffferent store results. In myphpadmin, they have the ID 1 and 2. But in these search results, both id for both stores is showing as 1. This means that something in my query is changing all results id to 1 regardless of what the results have for id in mysql. but it still returns the rest of the results correctly

Comment: You're right... Then try to continue var dump things and try to find where those values are coming from

Comment: I know. but that is what I can't figure out and it brings me back to my original question. I should have titled this "how to get echo id results from JOIN queries" perhaps....

Comment: Well, I solved it by changing SELECT * FROM stores  to   SELECT stores.id, name FROM stores.  So I guess the only way to is add every variable to the select part specifically instead of using select *